# How do I make the DOM display result of function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to select "archer" from the dropdown, click submit, and display the result of getTroopLostValue. Here is what I have so far.

```
    var troops = {
        spear: {
            wood: 50,
            clay: 30,
            iron: 10
        },
        sword:{
            wood: 30,
            clay: 30,
            iron: 70
        },
        axe: {
            wood: 60,
            clay: 30,
            iron: 40
        },
        archer:{
            wood: 100,
            clay: 30,
            iron: 60
        }
    }

    var spear = troops.spear;
    var sword = troops.sword;
    var axe = troops.axe;
    var archer = troops.archer;

    function getTroopLostValue(n, type="spear") { 
        n = parseInt(document.querySelector("#numberOfTroops").value);
        type = document.querySelector("[value='spear']").value;

        return {
            wood: troops[type].wood * n,
            clay: troops[type].clay * n,
            iron: troops[type].iron * n
        }    
    }

    function displayLost(){
        var displayLost = document.querySelector("#displayLost");
        displayLost.innerHTML = "<p>" + getTroopLostValue() + "</p>";
    }
```

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <select id="Troop Type">
                    <option value='spear'>Spear</option>
                </select>
                <input id="numberOfTroops" type="int" placeholder="# lost">
                <button onclick="getTroopLostValue();displayLost()">submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="displayLost"></div>
        </div>
```

I know that the problem is coming from this line but im not sure what to replace the getTroopsLostValue)( with... all the help is appreciated, thank you guys!

```
    displayLost.innerHTML = "<p>" + getTroopLostValue() + "</p>";
```

Comment: can you pleas describe your code in sections 1 imput: {} 2. i whant to acheve thi:"" 3. tryed this: "youre code"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Object, you can do `JSON.stringify(getTroopListValue())`. If you want to display a string in the format you want, you could do this:

```js
var troops = {
  spear: { wood: 50, clay: 30, iron: 10 },
  sword: { wood: 30, clay: 30, iron: 70 },
  axe: { wood: 60, clay: 30, iron: 40 },
  archer: { wood: 100, clay: 30, iron: 60 }
};

function getTroopLostValue(n, type = "spear") {
  var n = parseInt(document.querySelector("#numberOfTroops").value);
  var type = document.querySelector("[value='spear']").value;

  return {
    wood: troops[type].wood * n,
    clay: troops[type].clay * n,
    iron: troops[type].iron * n
  }
}

function objToString(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(function(v) {
    return v[0] + ": " + v[1];
  }).join(' | ');
}

function displayLost() {
  var displayLost = document.querySelector("#displayLost");
  var result = getTroopLostValue();
  displayLost.innerHTML = "<p>" + objToString(result) + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select id="Troop Type">
      <option value='spear'>Spear</option>
    </select>
    <input id="numberOfTroops" type="int" placeholder="# lost">
    <button onclick="getTroopLostValue();displayLost()">submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="displayLost"></div>
</div>
```